# how to save the value of a SeekBar and pass it to other activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm new in kotlin language and am trying to implement a `SeekBar` for resizing `TextView`s inside my setting activity and save its value by shared preference and then pass the values of the SeekBar to the main activity!

I tried  several answers but none of them seems to work for me!

**Setting Activity**

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun seekbarFontSize(){

    var savedProgress1:Int = 0
    val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    val editor = pref.edit()
    savedProgress1 = seekFontSize.progress
    editor.putInt("seekFonts", savedProgress1)
    editor.apply()
    seekFontSize.min = 20
    seekFontSize.max = 80
    seekbarCounter.text = "20"



        seekFontSize.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
       /**
        * Notification that the progress level has changed. Clients can use the fromUser parameter
        * to distinguish user-initiated changes from those that occurred programmatically.
        *
        * @param seekBar The SeekBar whose progress has changed
        * @param progress The current progress level. This will be in the range min..max where min
        * and max were set by [ProgressBar.setMin] and
        * [ProgressBar.setMax], respectively. (The default values for
        * min is 0 and max is 100.)
        * @param fromUser True if the progress change was initiated by the user.
        */
       override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
           textFont.textSize = progress.toFloat()
           textFont1.textSize = progress.toFloat()
           seekbarCounter.text = "$progress"

       }


       /**
        * Notification that the user has started a touch gesture. Clients may want to use this
        * to disable advancing the seekbar.
        * @param seekBar The SeekBar in which the touch gesture began
        */
       override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
           Toast.makeText(this@SettingActivity, "start tracking",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

       }

       /**
        * Notification that the user has finished a touch gesture. Clients may want to use this
        * to re-enable advancing the seekbar.
        * @param seekBar The SeekBar in which the touch gesture began
        */
       override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
           Toast.makeText(this@SettingActivity, "stop tracking",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }

   })
```

**MainAcitvity**

```
fun seekbarSizing(){
    val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("seek", 0)
    if (pref == 0){
        TitleEt.textSize = 20f
    }
    if (pref == 1){
        TitleEt.textSize = 50f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're updating your value when the `SeekBar` is moved. Moving your storage logic into the `onProgressChanged` method will work.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun seekbarFontSize() {

  seekFontSize.min = 20
  seekFontSize.max = 80
  seekbarCounter.text = "20"

  seekFontSize.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
      textFont.textSize = progress.toFloat()
      textFont1.textSize = progress.toFloat()
      seekbarCounter.text = "$progress"

      // You need to save the current progress when the SeekBar is changed.
      val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
      editor.putInt("seekFonts", savedProgress1)
      editor.apply()
    }

    // ... other methods
  }

})
```

Do note you're saving a value between 20 and 80, whereas your check is only for 0 and 1. You could use different min/max values on your `SeekBar` to make it easier to calculate the size, unless you're just wanting to use the actual value as a font size, such as 80.

Comment: It depends on how you're using it. You could use 0 to 100 and that would give you easy conversion to percent.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? It would save the value, are you using the value correctly?

Comment: I copied your code and it doesn't work my friend, when I put the SeekBar to 50 or 30..etc the shared preference doesn't save the SeekBar values when I go to main activity and return to the setting activity it would still be the same value which is 20>

Comment: @Abood You should debug it, ensure the right value is being written to your SeekBar while it's moved. If the text is updating, then it's saving. And you have code that would reset the value, I removed that in my example.